# mapping between metrics and ISO 25010 maintainability sub-chractristic

Tags: code-maintainability

Question/ What is the mapping between these metrics (LOC , CC , PC , NOF , NOPF , NOM, NOPM , WMC , NC , DIT , LCOM, FANIN , FANOUT)  and the  sub-characteristics of maintainability in the ISO 25010 standard (Modularity, Reusability, Analysability, Modifiability, Testability)?

to mesure the maintainability of design level